# If $G$ is a cyclic group with exactly two nontrivial proper subgroups, prove $|G| = pq$ or $|G| = p^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I can prove that $G$ is cyclic, but I am not sure how to prove the orders. I know I need to use the Fundamental Theorem of Cyclic Groups but I'm not sure how to apply it. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The subgroups of any finite cyclic group $G$ are in bijective correspondence with the divisors of $|G|$. Write $|G| = p_{1}^{k_{1}}p_{2}^{k_{2}}\cdots p_{n}^{k_{n}}$ for distinct primes $p_{1}, p_{2}, \ldots, p_{n}$ and positive integers $k_{1}, \ldots, k_{n}$. Then each divisor of $|G|$ can be specified by a tuple $(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \ldots, \alpha_{n})$ such that $0 \leqslant \alpha_{i} \leqslant k_{i}$, and each distinct tuple gives rise to a distinct divisor of $|G|$. Then one can see that the only way that $|G|$ can have exactly two nontrivial divisors (i.e., two divisors other than $1$ and $|G|$) is if $|G| = p^{3}$ (in which case the nontrivial divisors are $p, p^{2}$) or $|G| = pq$ (in which case the divisors are $p, q$).

Comment: Not quite. Can you please phrase it a different way? I don't just want the answer, I want to understand why

Comment: @user338113, see the formula for $\sigma_0$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Properties.

Comment: @user338113: I've updated my answer - let me know if this helps clarify things. lhf's link should also be helpful.

Comment: Both of those cleared it up a lot. I haven't learned Sylow's theorem like in the answer below so this way is much easier for me to grasp. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $|G|=m$ for a theorem due to a Sylow for each integer $p^i$ with $i$ integer and $p$ prime exist a subgroup of order $p^i$. For this motive you have two possibilities :$pq$ or $p^3$